# How can I get a bike mechanic certification/where can I learn to be a bike mechanic?

Tags: maintenance, lbs

I'm interested in becoming a bike mechanic in Melbourne, Victoria, Australia.

I'm hoping there's an industry body which runs courses to certify bike mechanics.

I'm really hoping it's not just learn on the job from an existing mechanic because I've had a really bad experience with local mechanics lately they don't have a clue what customer service is when I buy from them and need a return.

Are there any courses or certifications to become a bike mechanic?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no standardized certification mechanism in the US.  But I'm pretty sure that several bike/bike parts companies offer their own certifications, though not all particularly meaningful.

Comment: Do you actually want to learn to pick it up as a profession, or just to wrench on your own bikes? The majority of tools are not expensive and you can learn own your own reading the internet if the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.bicycletrainingaustralia.com.au/ is supported by the City of Melbourne. They provide Advanced Bicycle Mechanic Training.

In the UK, [Cytech](http://www.cytech.uk.com/about-cytech/) are the most recognised body; Contact them and ask if they're aware of an equivalent organisation in Australia.

Answer (score 3):

I'll tackle the question of where you can learn. Do an online seach and find out if you have a bike co-op nearby. Most decently sized US cities have them. They're a great resource where you can just show up one day per week and learn everything there is to know about bikes (and meet some cool people while you're at it).

Specifically for you: http://www.thebikeshed.org.au/default.aspx

Comment: Don't know that we have those in this country but I will look. So there is no certifcation, it's pretty much a passed down art, learned from apprentiships and on the job training?

Comment: @yoshiserry AFAIK that's the way it is in Oz.

Comment: @yoshiserry talk to your local bike shops, ask what they want. I suspect you will find that most focus more on customer service skills, as there are relatively few mechanic-only roles in the industry. In somewhat circular fashion, the limited training/certification options mean most shops don't ask for them and might not know anything about them if you have them.

Answer (score 1):

In Germany, there's the "Zweiradmechaniker", which is taught like any other craft, i.e. you learn it from an existing mechanic. You don't need to have this education to open a bike store though.

Comment: that sounds great. it should be mandatory, bike stores in my country suck.

One just last week told me that the deraluer hanger I said was bent by the machine, couldn't be bent by hand. I said exactly, proves my point it was bent by the machine in china that made it. I said I want refund he was like we only refund our workmanship. He didn't grasp it was faulty. Germany always seems ahead of this country for trades, physics, maths, technology and automation.

Comment: @yoshiserry There are also very crappy bike stores here  that are operated by a Zweiradmechanikermeister, i.e. one that is allowed to take on apprentices. The training doesn't necessarily make a good mechanic. The love for his job is the key.